# Resultado en pantalla repetido C++

Tags: c++

Cuando busco alumno me sale dos veces el resultado o me vuelve al menu anterior. Este es mi código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define TOTAL 1000

using namespace std;

struct Alumno
{
    char apellido[50];
    char nombre[50];
    int dni;
    int legajo;
};

int Ingresar_Alumno (int &e)
{
    FILE *cho;
    Alumno vectoralumno[TOTAL];

    if (cho=fopen("cho.dat", "wb+"))
    {
            cout << "ingrese el nombre del alumno: ";
            cin >> vectoralumno[e].nombre;

            cout << "ingrese el apellido del alumno: ";
            cin >> vectoralumno[e].apellido;

            cout << "ingrese legajo del alumno: ";
            cin >> vectoralumno[e].legajo;

            cout << "ingrese el DNI del alumno: ";
            cin >> vectoralumno[e].dni;

        fwrite(vectoralumno,sizeof(struct Alumno),1,cho);

        }
    fclose(cho);
    e++;
}

void BuscarDNI(int dni, int &q)
{
    Alumno dchof;
    FILE *x;
    if(x=fopen("cho.dat","rb"))
    {
        fseek(x,0,SEEK_SET);

        while (!feof(x))
        {

            fread(&dchof,sizeof(struct Alumno),1,x);

            if(dni == (dchof.dni))
            {
                Search:
                cout << "El alumno buscado es: " << endl;
                cout << "Nombre: " << dchof.nombre << endl;
                cout << "Apellido: " << dchof.apellido << endl;
                cout << "Legajo: " << dchof.legajo << endl;
                cout << "DNI: " << dchof.dni << endl;
                cout<< "Toque cualquier boton para volver al menu anterior" << endl;
                getch();
            }
        }
        if(dni!=dchof.dni)
        {
            cout<< "Error: DNI Incorrecto" << endl;
            cout<< "Toque cualquier boton para volver al menu anterior" << endl;
            getch();
        }
    }
    fclose(x);
}

int main()
{
    int a,op=0,e=0,q=0;
    int dni;
    MainMenu:
do
{

    system("cls");
    cout << "Elija alguna opcion para empezar" << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << "1 - Ingresar nuevo alumno" << endl;
    cout << "2 - Buscar alumno" << endl;
    cout << "3 - " << endl;
    cout << "4 - " << endl;
    cout << "5 -  " << endl;
    cout << "6 - Salir" << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << "Ingrese una opcion deseada: ";
    cin >> op;
    system("cls");
    switch (op)
    {
        case 1:

            Ingresar_Alumno(e);
            system("cls");
        break;

        case 2:

            cout<< "Buscar alumno por DNI: ";
            cin >> dni;
            BuscarDNI(dni,q);

        break;

        case 3:
        break;

        case 6:
        break;

        default:
            cout<< "ERROR: OPCION INCORRECTA "<< endl;
            getch();
            system ("cls");
            break;
    }
}while(op!=6);
return 0;
}
```

Una captura de mi programa en funcionamiento: [image]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] Salva. Unas observaciones; deberias explicar con algo más de detalle que es lo que hace tu programa, qué debería hacer, el error, etc. Tómate algo de tiempo en redactar de forma que quede fácil de entender para posibles lectores sin tener que recurrir a descifrar el código. Por otro lado, debes formatear el código adecuadamente, para ello lo seleccionas y pulsas el botón `{}` del editor o Ctrl + k. Mirate [ask] y [tour] para más información. Saludos.

Comment: No pongas una captura de pantalla, **describe tu error**. Para que te podamos ayudar debes ayudarnos a ayudarte, no dejar que adivinemos tu problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (!feof(x))
{
  fread(&dchof,sizeof(struct Alumno),1,x);
```

Tu estás asumiendo que `feof` inspecciona el fichero y comprueba si el puntero interno se encuentra al final del fichero... y no es así. `feof` consulta un flag que se activa cuando se realiza una operación que **sobrepasa** el final del fichero.

Es decir, si tu tienes 2 registros en el fichero obtendrás la siguiente secuencia:

- `feof() == 0`
- `fread()` se lee el primer registro
- `feof() == 0`
- `fread()` se lee el segundo registro
- `feof() == 0`
- `fread()` lectura errónea
- `feof() == 1`

Una forma más adecuada de programar esta parte podría ser así:

```
if(x=fopen("cho.dat","rb"))
{
  fseek(x,0,SEEK_SET); // (1)

  fread(&dchof,sizeof(struct Alumno),1,x);
  while (!feof(x))
  {
    if(dni == (dchof.dni))
    {
      // ...
    }

    fread(&dchof,sizeof(struct Alumno),1,x);
  }
  // ...
}
```

**Nota:** La línea con el comentario es una línea que te puedes ahorrar. Al abrir un fichero en modo lectura, el puntero interno **siempre** se va a encontrar al inicio del mismo.

Si no te gusta repetir la línea de `fread` puedes intentar algo tal que:

```
if(x=fopen("cho.dat","rb"))
{
  while ( true )
  {
    fread(&dchof,sizeof(struct Alumno),1,x);
    if( feof(x) )
      break;

    if(dni == (dchof.dni))
    {
      // ...
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```

Incluso, ya que estás en C++, si compilas con C++11 o superior podrías usar una lambda:

```
if(x=fopen("cho.dat","rb"))
{
  auto lambda = [&](){
    fread(&dchof,sizeof(struct Alumno),1,x);
    return feof();
  };

  while ( lambda() )
  {
    if(dni == (dchof.dni))
    {
      // ...
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```

Aunque claro, ya puestos a programar en C++ quizás deberías echarle un vistazo a las clases propias de C++ para la gestión de ficheros.

Comment: no se que problema hay ahora que a partir que ingreso el segundo alumno en adelante es como si no me lo guardara en el archivo. Ej. Ingreso un alumo, lo busco y me lo muestra en pantalla, pero cuando ingreso el segundo alumno o un tercero, un cuarto etc, y lo voy a buscar me tira: "Error: DNI Incorrecto Toque cualquier boton para volver al menu anterior" y el dni esta bien ingreso en ambos terminos (tanto cuando ingreso el alumno y cuando lo busco). @eferion

Comment: @SalvaCastro una vez has modificado tu código y es diferente al de la pregunta es imposible conocer su estado desde fuera... Si este error ya está solucionado marca la respuesta que más te haya ayudado como solución y publica una nueva pregunta... si no la pregunta se acaba convirtiendo en algo infumable con multitud de cambios tanto en la pregunta como en las respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

## El While (!feof(x))

Ese es el problema. Cuando lees la primera linea

```
fread(&dchof,sizeof(struct Alumno),1,x);
```

fread devuelve un valor; si la lectura es correcta, fread devuelve el número total de elementos leidos satisfactoriamente, en otro caso devolverá un error

En tu caso, primero lees la linea y guardas el resultado en dchof. Entonces comparas, imprimes y el ciclo se vuelve a realizar (porque no se ha llegado al final del archivo), la funcion fread se vuelve a ejecutar, y allí devuelve que efectivamente se ha llegado al final del archivo, pero no sobreescribe dchof, por lo que la comparación vuelve a ser positiva y se vuelve a imprimir el resultado.

## El While ( fread() )

Existen muchas formas de solventar este error. Una que a mi me gusta es esta: Hacer el while directamente con lo que quiero leer:

```
 while ( fread(&dchof,sizeof(struct Alumno),1,x) )
 {

    if(dni == (dchof.dni))
    {
        Search:
        cout << "El alumno buscado es: " << endl;
        cout << "Nombre: " << dchof.nombre << endl;
        cout << "Apellido: " << dchof.apellido << endl;
        cout << "Legajo: " << dchof.legajo << endl;
        cout << "DNI: " << dchof.dni << endl;
        cout<< "Toque cualquier boton para volver al menu anterior" << endl;
        getch();
     }
 }
```

Saludos

Comment: Jacobo, no se que problema hay ahora que a partir que ingreso el segundo alumno en adelante es como si no me lo guardara en el archivo. Ej. Ingreso un alumo, lo busco y me lo muestra en pantalla, pero cuando ingreso el segundo alumno o un tercero, un cuarto etc, y lo voy a buscar me tira: "Error: DNI Incorrecto
Toque cualquier boton para volver al menu anterior" y el dni esta bien ingreso en ambos terminos (tanto cuando ingreso el alumno y cuando lo busco)

Comment: Si en realidad no lo esta guardando en el archivo, y eso tiene que ver con la forma en como lo estas guardando. Tendrias que abrir el archivo en modo de append y luego en el final agregar un nuevo estudiante. (eso es una manera) o podrias pasar el vector como referencia a la funcion y reescribir cada vez en el archivo( eso es otra manera)

Comment: Lo puse en modo en a y a+ tanto en el primer if de BuscarAlumno e Ingresar_Alumno y no tuve suerte. Los puse asi if (cho=fopen("cho.dat", "a"))//if(x=fopen("cho.dat","a")) las barras no van es para separarlos, el primero es de BuscarAlumno y el segundo es de Ingresar_Alumno. Esta bien hecho asi no?

Comment: Bien, no esta bien hecho porque para leer no debes ponerlo en append, solo para escribir.. y mi recomendacion es que uses la cabecera `<fstream>` ya que estas en c++ y utilices un ofstream que te haria mucho mas facil la vida. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/is_open/